# wp_list_pages as text not link

Tags: php, wordpress

im doing the follow to get the children of the page im currently administrating:

```
    $args = array(
    'depth' => 0,
    'child_of' => get_the_ID(),
    'title_li' => '',
    'echo' => 0,
);

wp_list_pages($args);
```

The output is the title of the subpages and it is linked, what i wish to do is to serperate the title and the link so the output would be something like
"http://thelink.com title".

Is this possible?

Regards, Emil

Comment: you want to print child pages in custom html ?

Comment: Yes that would be great :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, Enjoy

if **`$post->ID`** and `get_the_ID()` same then use **`$post->ID`**

```
global $post;
$currentPageID = $post->ID;

    $Childpages = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&hierarchical=0&parent=' . $currentPageID . '&exclude=');

foreach ($Childpages as $page){
echo "Child Page ID: ".$page->ID ."<br>";
echo "Child Page Name: ".$page->post_title ."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Your are a legend sir!

Comment: One more thing, whats is the shorthand for getting the url? as $page->ID gets the ID what would i type to get the url of that page?

Comment: Sorry for spamming, Did this to get the url: echo get_page_link($page->ID); probably not the easy way but "good enough" :)